# How to deploy x86 compile code on SharePoint server 2010 ( x64)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, odp.net

I'm creating visual web part project which connects Oracle database using ODP.NET. When I deploy on SharePoint server 2010 , web part gives Oracle dll missing error. Even I tried to compile in x86 or Any CPU but it gives error. Here is the error,

[image]

SharePoint server 2010 is running on my machine whereas Oracle server is running on different machine. I've verified the code in normal ASP web application and it successfully connects Oracle server.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint 2010 is 64-bit only.

Comment: John, I'm compiling my Visual web part project with "Any CPU" option then it should be deployed on SharePoint server 2010 ?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2010 is a 64bit process, so it can only load x64 or Any CPU assemblies.
Be careful that all your assemblies, **and all dependencies**, have to be x64 or Any CPU.

In your case, I guess you linked to a x86 version of the Oracle assembly. You'll have to install Oracle in x64 mode.

Comment: Nico,

I tried "ODAC112021Xcopy_x64" ODP.NET with "win64_11gR2_client" but with this I even can't compile my code in ASP.NET app. Even in warning it says "Assembly generation - Ref assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess.dll' targets a different processor" . I can't compile code in either x86 , x64 or Any CPU. Now I started believing , 

**(VS 2010 + Windows 7 64x + Oracle Client x64 + ODP.NET x64 = Doesn't work )**
But
**(VS 2010 + Windows 7 64x + Oracle Client x64 + ODP.NET x32 = Works)**